# Chart.js Pie Chart: How to Make Data Labels Stay Fixed Relative to Segments?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, chart.js

I'm using Chart.js to create a pie chart with data labels. However, I'm encountering an issue where the data labels rotate freely instead of staying fixed relative to their respective segments when the chart spins.

I've tried various approaches, including adjusting the rotation settings and using custom rotation functions, but none seem to produce the desired result. The data labels should remain stable and follow the movement of their corresponding segments as the chart spins , this is my code :

```
 const myChart = new Chart(wheel, {
      plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
      type: "pie",
      data: {
        labels: chartData.options.map((elem) => elem.title),
        datasets: [
          {
            backgroundColor: pieColors,
            data: data,
            borderWidth: 0,
          },
        ],
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        animation: { duration: 1 },
        plugins: {
          tooltip: false,
          legend: { display: false },
          datalabels: {
            color: chartData.options.map((elem) => elem.text_color),
            font: {
              family: "Poppins",
              size: 13,
              weight: "bold",
              lineHeight: 1.3,
              style: "oblique",
            },
            rotation: [-60, -10, 45, 90, -35, 12, 75],
            textAlign: "center",
            formatter: function (value, context) {
              const dataIndex = context.dataIndex;
              return chartData.options[dataIndex].title.toUpperCase(); // Convert text to uppercase
            },
          },
        },
        border: {
          display: true,
          borderColor: "#c66e16",
        },
      },
    });
```

i tried fixing the rotation values but it didn't work !

Comment: You probably have to set the `datalabels.rotation` as a function of the overall rotation. You should provide the rotation code for a precise answer